# How to simply make it private for general public? Without changing anything for my script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I'm kind of a newbie to AWS. I have the following data:

```
bucket ARN: arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket555
user: my-user-555
Access Key ID: "some key"
Secret access key: "some secret key"
```

And I have this policy of a bucket:

```
      {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
              },
              "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket555"
          },
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
              },
              "Action": [
                  "s3:PutObject",
                  "s3:GetObject",
                  "s3:DeleteObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket555/*"
          }
      ]
  }
```

And also I have a bash script on a VPS which does some staff with my AWS account **via API using the standard cli utility "aws s3" of Amazon.** and the API keys

**Problem:** my bucket is publicly available at "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket555". The url is obfuscated.

**Question**: how to make it private/non-public and still allow my bash script continue doing the job it's doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a few ways to accomplish that.**

First, set as private your bucket.

## Alternatives

1. Create an IAM Group and set it that policy, create a user within that group and use the access keys in your bash script.
2. Add to the policy a `Condition` to only accept accesses from a specific IP.

---

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket555",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "210.75.12.75/16",
            "210.75.24.75/16"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket555/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "210.75.12.75/16",
            "210.75.24.75/16"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: 1) will my script still be able to do the API operations?

Comment: 2) why ip addresses? what are they for? I don't want them.

Comment: 1. Your script will still be able to execute API calls.  2. The IP address is an alternative because you said you're executing the bash script from a VPS, so I'm assuming you're outside of AWS infrastructure.  The IP address condition close the scope of accesses from specific IP addresses to your bucket.

Comment: 1) ok. how to make my bucket private?  2). can I simply that somehow? for instance, without having to create a new user/group? I want to keep that as simple as possible

Comment: 1) I've removed completely my current policy shown in my question and now my script has no access either ----> `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied` How's your 1st solution supposed to work?

Comment: @Ramito go to s3 console, click on your bucket, click on permission tab and uncheck all read/write options at Public access section.  That will set your bucket as private.  Now, if you want your bash script gains access to your bucket, follow one of the alternatives I wrote in this answer.  You still need your Policy to grant access to your bash script.

Comment: I don't understand. **Alternative** means that I may do either of them. How's that Alternative if I still must  do both?

Comment: @Ramito you only need to follow one alternative only.  Look my answer, the first is set as private and then follow one alternatives I’ve written.

Comment: Got it. I'll try to.

Comment: it's working but it's also "access denied" when I'm trying to access it via my amazon dashboard -- `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/`. How to  fix that?

Comment: @Ramito you’re saying you’re unable to open the bucket from your s3 console? Or trying to open clicking the bucket’s link?

Comment: Both -- from my s3 console, logged in, I can't actually download a file in my bucket when I click on a link.

Comment: @Ramito that’s fine, the only way is using your policy through SDK calls or CLI commands.  That’s the purpose of the policies to keep safe yours files.